# Where is the save data stored on each platform?

Tags: crawl

[Crawl](http://www.powerhoof.com/crawl/) just released on early access and it is pretty sweet.
Sadly, one of the features it does not yet boast is syncing save data through the Steam cloud. I've unlocked a few things on my laptop during my various playthroughs and would certainly love that progress to transfer to my desktop.

Could anyone shed some light as to where the game stores its data on each platform (Win/Max/Linux)?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName I can't seem to find the "saves" folder you're talking about. A full path would be better.

Comment: @Aubergine - not the answer you wanted, but it seems as though, according to the several steam forum posts I've found, it is not yet possible to do this. If it becomes so at some point, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, and [I quote the developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/293780/discussions/0/37470848073166066/#c34094415695332682) on this, there is currently

> no easy way to move saves [...] due to the way they're stored

Steam cloud seems to be a priority, so this will possibly be a moot point in the future.